# It's ever pass in method oncreate when i call setResult(100,i) and finish()

Tags: android, oncreate

I've a problem. In device SAMSUNG GT-P3110, when i call to screen searchProducts, selected  product and go back using:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("productID", "1");
setResult(100,i);
finish();
```

It's always pass in method on oncreate in class caller, cleaning all member class.
In some devices the behavior is normal, it's pass just once.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you share more information/code that can help characterize the problem you are having? Maybe let us know exactly what you are expecting this code to do, and what you are observing. Posting your logcat or additional source code would probably be beneficial as well.

Answer (score 0):

I researched and found that the device has a function that limits the number of open activities. unchecked the option and it's passing in method oncreate only once.